# Re usable, thread safe cmponents in commons-fileupload

Tags: java, file-upload, multipartform-data, apache-commons-fileupload

I am using commons-fileupload to read image file from the POST request using classes DiskFileItemFactory and ServletFileUpload.

Can someone help me with which objects off the above can be re-used and accessed concurrently among threads or will have to be created anew for each request

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not get any straight point in this direction. 
But found the Streaming API of the commons file upload [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/streaming.html). 
Since it creates one ServletFileUpload object, So I think this migh be a better idea.

`// Create a new file upload handler
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();`

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is not informative on this respect. The available examples suggest that all the objects are to be recreated on each request, except the `FileCleaningTracker` for which a static method is suggested when building the DiskFileItemFactories as shown in https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html:

```
public static DiskFileItemFactory newDiskFileItemFactory(ServletContext context,
                                                     File repository) {
  FileCleaningTracker fileCleaningTracker
    = FileCleanerCleanup.getFileCleaningTracker(context);
  DiskFileItemFactory factory
    = new DiskFileItemFactory(DiskFileItemFactory.DEFAULT_SIZE_THRESHOLD,
                              repository);
  factory.setFileCleaningTracker(fileCleaningTracker);
  return factory;
}
```